# In what way can I see the rotating hub and the bullet that has just been fired clearly with the naked eye?

Tags: optics, visible-light

In what way can I see the rotating hub and the bullet that has just been fired clearly with the naked eye?  Some people say that you can place a shutter in front of your eyes, and then adjust the shutter to a suitable speed.  Is this method feasible?

Answer (score 2):

A very bright, very brief flashes of light are all that's needed.  Let's say that the bullet moves at 2 km per second. That's 2 nanometers per nanosecond. There are lots of lasers that emit pulses of a nanosecond or less.  A bullet is, say, 2 cm long and you would want something like 10 "frames" in a movie during the time that the bullet moves a distance equal to its length; so 10 frames per 20 microseconds.  That, too, is easily achievable.  A mechanical shutter won't do it, but a laser strobe will.

Edit 10/3/2020: A single pulse, bright enough, would make the bullet briefly appear to the naked eye to be suspended in mid-air.  A bullet illuminated by train of bright pulses, microseconds apart, would appear to the naked eye as a streak.

On the other hand, when shooting a .22 rifle in bright sunshine against a dark background, I have sometimes been able to see the bullet in flight.  Its change of *angular* position is negligible since I'm gazing straight down its path of travel.

Comment: I have seen pictures of speeding bullets taken using standard strobes.

Comment: Nice thing about a "laser strobe" is that the pulses can be so brief that no resolution is lost due to motion blur.

Comment: But the question asks about the naked eve, not a camera

Comment: Please see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Can you use your method to see a clear picture of a bullet still?

Comment: Not by eye.  The image will be gone almost immediately.  But a clear photo could be taken by that method.

Answer (score 1):

While a bullet may have its image captured by high speed cameras, its speed is normally just too great to be seen by the naked eye if you and the gun are at rest with each other. Even using shutters or strobes the bullet would have high a speed and too great of a space between frames for the naked eye to observe it. As for a spinning hub, either a properly synchronized shutter or strobe light can allow the naked eye to see it in stop motion, slow motion, or reverse motion. This is similar to the effects of how wagon wheels and aircraft propellers may appear in movies.

Comment: Can't the bullet reach the freeze-frame effect of the wheel?

Comment: @enbin Most bullets travel well over 300 meters per second, even if you could perceive an image from a 1/30th of a second flash the bullet would move over 10 meters in that flash. A rotating hub or wheel does not usually move this fast, but even if it did a strobe or shutter could be timed to flash the same position over and over again so it would appear to the naked eye as standing still. But a bullet will only make a single pass, so any single flash to "freeze frame" it would be far to fast for the eye to perceive an image.